# Genomic Ranges - Merge Overlaps in Single File (R STUDIO)

Tags: merge, overlap, overlapping, genomicranges, iranges

**I would like to find overlapped regions in the file and merge them keeping the earlier start and the later stop (merge 2 regions in 1)**

**I meant to use Genomic Ranges but I am not sure how to code the script.**

This is what the file **fileA.txt** contain:

```
chr     start       end       value
chr1    58708485    58708713  1
chr1    58709084    58710538  2
chr1    98766295    98766639  3
chr1    98766902    98770338  4
```

Script:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
query = with(fileA.txt, GRanges(chr, IRanges(start=start, end=end)))
subject = with(fileA.txt, GRanges(chr, IRanges(start=start, end=end)))
hits = findOverlaps(gr1)
ranges(query)[queryHits(hits)] = ranges(subject)[subjectHits(hits)]
```

**I am not sure how to set query and subject for a single file, as well the object being a document need any kind of "" or specific format (bedGraph, txt are fine?) in order to be recognised in the script?**

Thank you a lot in advance for your help!

K.